# What is the difference between "Inverse source problem" and "inverse scattering problem"?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, terminology, radiation, scattering

As above in the title. I know the inverse scattering problem problem in the context of recovering dielectric profile of imaging domain from scattered fields measured at certain locations. But, what **is** the inverse source problem?

Comment: Hi there. Welcome to this SE site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! The difference is simply the setup:

- In a **scattering problem**, one considers a wave (or particle or whatever else you can shoot at stuff) traveling towards a target. The interaction with the target causes the wave to be deformed (or the particle to bounce off in a different direction), i.e. scattered.
- In a **source problem**, one does not have the incoming wave/particle. Instead, the target itself emits a wave (for example photons).

In summary, you have an outgoing wave/particle stream in both cases, but only in the scattering stream you have an incoming one too.

- The **inverse scattering problem** is then the task of reconstructing a target's properties from the information one can get from scattering experiments.
- By analogy, the **inverse source problem** is the task of reconstructing a source's properties from the information one can get from its emitted radiation/particles.

Also check out the wikipedia article on [Inverse Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem).